# Testing a Journey, records appear to be considered for Entry, but nothing happens

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I have built my Journey and am trying to test it.

I've placed the Journey into "Test" mode, but nothing seems to be happening. I can see that "**12 Contacts to be Evaluated**," which aligns with my test data, but after the test runs nothing happens - and the "**Contacts to be Evaluated**" goes to 0, and "**Contacts Evaluated**" also equals 0.

Some additional info to share

- Journey Builder Automation step in Automation Studio has successfully ran each time.
- The Automation step is not listed as an **Entry Source** even though it is showing how many records to evaluate.
- The Data Extension where names are housed is linked in Contact Builder as an Attribute Group.
- The Journey is set to TEST (not Active, and not Draft).

Will results populate in TEST mode?  Am I missing something obvious here?   Is there any information I didn't provide that we think is useful?

THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: Is your Entry event set in Test Mode ?

Comment: @Maneesh - as I stated above, the Automation step is not listed as an Entry Source. 

However, I just created a new Entry Source and it should run in 20 minutes, but I'm confused because I also have **Journey Entry: Audience
Welcome_AUG2017** that runs but nothing happens (although it shows that it ran successfully in Automation Studio)

Comment: Is your Automation Audience based on a Query? If so, there could be an error in there.  Are you getting any error codes in the Activity Log?  

Is this Version 1 of the Journey?  If not, you might want to look at your re-entry criteria for the journey.